# How fast in mph is water when released from dam, a point of exit , as a baseball is clocked in mph when released from a pitchers arm

Tags: water, speed

How fast in mph is water when released from dam, at point of exit ,  as a baseball is clocked in mph when released from a pitchers arm .
I am a complete novice and looked all over for an answer

Comment: Can you please look over your question again? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer , and apologize for not asking the question correctly. I cant figure out the equation. I'm not capable. They say tha wind mills top speed per hour is 50 - 55 mphe. The earth rotates at a 1000 miles per hour . I was wondering how fast the water can travel out of the most powerful dam. –

Comment: What are you talking about wind mills and the rotation of the Earth? Now I am really confused

Comment: @Bobby weiss : may I try and rewrite the question to make it clearer? I think I know what you mean and also gave an answer already but want to run it past little *You*. (#meep.)

Answer (score 1):

[Torricelli's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law) states (from Wikipedia):

> the speed v of efflux of a fluid through a sharp-edged hole at the
>   bottom of a tank filled to a depth *h* is the same as the speed that a
>   body (in this case a drop of water) would acquire in falling freely
>   from a height *h* ...

That being:

$\sqrt{2gh}$

So it depends on the distance between the height of the damn and the hole, but not (in this equation) on the size of the hole (although in theory very small and very large holes will make a difference).

So, for example, if $h$ was $20\mathrm{m}$ and $g$ being approximately $10\mathrm{m/s^2}$ then it would be about $20\mathrm{m/s}$.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer , and apologize for not asking the question correctly. I cant figure out the equation. I'm not capable.  They say tha wind mills top speed per hour is 50 - 55 mphe. The earth rotates at a 1000 miles per hour . I was wondering how fast the water can travel out of the most powerful dam.

Comment: It depends on the distance from the surface of the water to the hole in the dam. To work it out, use a calculator. Take the height, times by 20, press square-root, then times by two. That is the speed in miles-per-hour.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking. You want to know what, in the scheme or hierarchy of speeds, where that a windmill spins at 50-55 MPH, and the Earth (at the equator, actually!) spins at 1000 MPH, (and a car drives at 65 MPH on the highway, a well-hit baseball by a strong hitter may go 100 MPH, etc.) where does the efflux from a dam rank in this?

In that case, then @rghome has the right answer. The equation is

$$v_\mathrm{efflux}\ \text{(speed of efflux)} = \sqrt{2gh}$$

You substitute the height of the dam for $h$, and $g$ is the gravity at the Earth's surface. It equals 9.8 meters per second per second (approx). or about 22 MPH/s. The latter figure is what you want to use to get speed in MPH. As the square root of a number gets larger the larger the number, then the speed grows with increasing height of the dam ($h$). So to find the fastest efflux we just need the tallest dam. Google says this is the Jinping-I dam in China, with a height of some 305 m. The water at the bottom of the dam would thus release at 77 m/s or **172 MPH.** Other damns will be shorter and will thus not be capable of as much speed.

However, as he says, it depends on just how high up the dam the port of exit is: this would be the maximum possible speed attainable for that dam were that port to be placed at the very bottom. If it is placed higher, then you need to subtract that from the height, and the speed will be lower. But insofar as "the most powerful damn", I would call this a good answer to your question, because it is the most powerful that *could* be achieved with a real life dam that really exists.

Comment: Yes I want to thank you very much for taking your time and sharing your knowledge with me .

Comment: @bobby weiss : aww ❤️#meep. ❤️#mehhr. you're welcome :) Do you like this answer? You can press the check mark that should be next to it to accept it.